# Django can I split tabularinline fields into multiple lines?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have an inline with many fields to show in an admin.tabularinline.
what is the easiest way to split those fields into multiple lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use can use a [`StackedInline`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.StackedInline) instead

Comment: thank you. With StackedInline, I used fieldsets to control what is displayed on each line.